# Define enums within a method in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, coding-style

I have mainly a C++ background and I am learning C#. So, I need some help with C# idioms and style.

I am trying to write, in C#, a small text-file parsing method in which I need a simple state variable with three states. In C++ I would declare an `enum` like this for the state variable:

```cpp
enum { stHeader, stBody, stFooter} state = stBody;
```

...and then use it in my parsing loop like this:

```cpp
if (state == stHeader && input == ".endheader")
{
  state = stBody;
}
```

In C# I realize that it is not possible to declare an `enum` inside a method. So, what I am supposed to do for sake of clean style? Declare this internal `enum` outside of the method? Use magic numbers 1,2,3? Create a separate class for this?

Please help me clear up my confusion.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but what's the point of an enum if it's used in a single method only?

Comment: @Dogget - give readable names to states.Otherwise I would have to write if (state == 2 && input == ".endheader") state = 1;

Comment: Self-annotation of state etc. It's very common practice in C, ie in the example given - to have state as something more meaningful than an int.

It comes up less often in C# I have to say - primarily because you tend to break methods down into smaller components, objects etc, rather than C which is far more imperative orientated. Or C++ when it's used similar to C for that matter.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The closest you can get is a private nested enum with in the class:

```
public class TheClass
{
    private enum TheEnum 
    {
       stHeader, 
       stBody, 
       stFooter
    }

    // ...the rest of the methods properties etc... 
}
```

Comment: This is perverted because the states have absolute no meaning outside the method. It is like declaring loop variables outside the method. Moreover, you need to give it a name!

Comment: Welcome to the world of conservative enterprise languages. It could be worse though, it could be java :D

Comment: @danatel: I don't make the rules :)

Comment: @willem van Rumpt. Thanks for the answer. For me, declaring three independent consts (const int stHeader=0; ) looks like lesser evil.

Comment: @danatel: I would've gone for the enumeration myself, but essentially, it boils down to the same thing :)

Comment: No it's not perverted... In the CLR world, the smallest unit of encapsulation is a type. It's types and their methods the CLR deals with.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the constant variables but I prefer and I think is better code style to use 
Enums

```
 public class Class1
{
    private enum TheEnum
    {
        stHeader,
        stBody,
        stFooter
    }
    public void SomeMethodEnum()
    {
        TheEnum state = TheEnum.stBody;
        switch (state)
        {
            case TheEnum.stHeader:
                //do something
                break;
            case TheEnum.stBody:
                break;
            case TheEnum.stFooter:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }


    public void SomeMethodConst()
    {
        int state = 1;
        const int Header = 1;
        const int Body = 2;
        const int Footer = 3;

        switch (state)
        {
            case Header:
                break;
            case Body:
                break;
            case Footer:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also favour the Enum approach. Plus, although that is not the case here, it has advantages over the CONSTS when you want to combine them as flags, since you have a method to easily test for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare an `enum` in method scope (recapping [Willem van Rumpt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5603939/3396951) above) but instead you can declare an inner private class to do the state-tracking and reuse it in your class methods. The containing class or its clients need not know about that auxiliary class.

```
class Program
{
    private class Parser
    {
        public string pname = "ParserPam"; 
        public enum pstate { rewind=-1, stdHeader, stBody, stFooter }

        public pstate state = pstate.stdHeader; 

        //Implement state transition logic as methods
        public void tick() => this.state = pstate.stBody;
        public void tock() => this.state = pstate.stFooter;
        public void rewind() => this.state = this.state - 1;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{this.pname} state: {this.state}";
        }
    }

    static void ParseFile(string filename)
    { 
        Parser fp = new Parser(); //This object tracks your method's state

        Console.WriteLine(fp); // "ParserPam state: stdHeader"
        if (fp.state == Parser.pstate.stdHeader)
        { 
            fp.tick(); // Transition
            // Do stuff
        }

        // Do more stuff
        Console.WriteLine(fp); // "ParserPam state: stBody"
        fp.tock();
        Console.WriteLine(fp); // "ParserPam state: stFooter"
        fp.rewind();
        Console.WriteLine(fp); // "ParserPam state: stBody"
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParseFile( @"C:\Example" ); // Client call
    }
}
```

In this case, `Parser` is your private inner class whose instances can track state -- it is not visible outside of `Program`. `ParseFile` is a method that utilizes `Parser`.

**Output**

```
ParserPam state: stdHeader
ParserPam state: stdBody
ParserPam state: stFooter
ParserPam state: stBody
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, so this is mainly for folks looking for ideas.

The closest I can think of to creating an 'enum' type, clean structure as required, within a method is to use a dictionary.

```
var stateOpt = new Dictionary<string, byte>() { { "stHeader", 0 }, { "stBody", 1 }, { "stFooter", 2 } };
var state = stateOpt["stBody"];
```

You can then do what you need in your condition...

```
if (state == stateOpt["stHeader"] && input == ".endheader")
{
  state = stateOpt["stBody"];
}
```

Comment: The OP wasn't asking for the most efficient or cost effective, they were asking 'the sake of clean style', and I think that's nice and clean.